# Vertex Group selects too many edges/faces

Tags: mesh, vertex-groups

I selected the edge of my object to make a vertex group. But when pressing the select button there are obviously extra edges assigned to that group. how can I get rid of them? I want to have a vertex group including ONLY the edges around the object. (remove doesn't work since it also removes some of the edges I want to keep.)

[image: Edges I want to assign]

[image: Vertex group with extra edges]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vertex groups are groups of vertices, if you put 2 vertices in a group and if there's an edge between these vertices, the edge will be selected when you'll select the vertex group, i.e. when you'll select these vertices, because edges are always selected between selected vertices:

[image]

If there's a vertex between these 2 vertices and it is not part of the vertex group, the edge won't be selected:

[image]

Actually it would be useful to know why you're bothered by the edges selection and what you want to use the vertex groups for?

Comment: I don't know the problem of the OP, but this behavior often gets in my way, e.g. if I want to remember a selection of 2 opposite faces of a cube, saving that to a vertex group and loading from there is an equivalent of pressing **1** then **3** - the face selection information is lost and is recalculated based on vertices. Face maps can be used instead, but they have their own limitations (e.g. a face can be only in a single face map). I use a script, but it's tricky (in short: `[p.index for p in C.active_object.data.polygons if p.select]`), oh and there's no edge maps.

Comment: yes that's why it would be interesting to know how it is a problem for the OP